# Python. Pygame. Нужно сделать так, чтобы противники появлялись в нужном месте

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, координаты

Вот у меня вопрос: что мне заменить или добавить/удалить, чтобы у меня противники не появлялись там же где и мой корабль? Как я понял ошибка в том что я использовал self.rect.x и self.rect.y в корабле и врагах. Я думаю мне нужно везде где связано с кораблём заменить на self.rect.centerx и self.rect.centery, но тогда нужно будет ещё дописывать код, чтобы он упирался в нужном месте... Можно ли это как-то сделать попроще или же нужно заменять? В таком случае возникает ещё вопрос... Если мне понадобится ещё и другие координаты? К примеру будет босс? Я не хочу чтобы он появлялся там-же где и противники! Код с архивом я прикрепил. Если что enemy.py - противники gun.py - мой корабль MAIN.py - сама основа bullet.py - пульки controls.py - обработка. Кстати код если его запустить то он работает. В будущем собираюсь добавить рандомный перелёт чубриков, но это без проблем. Идея есть. Для начатия игры достаточно открыть MAIN.py. Спасибо за понимание. Если нужен код сюда, то скажите и я сделаю. Но в таком случае файлы открываться без картинок не будут.

Сама ссылочка:

[Тыкни сюда](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14XcSjIxstzBAaWHG6j9vLTtdwWKNS72M?usp=sharing)

Comment: Вопрос имеет очевидный ответ и мыслите вы верно, продолжайте и все получится

Comment: @AlexanderChernin это конечно всё хорошо, но ведь мне придётся и других мобов расставлять по другому... Ладно. Скопирую в другую папку для сохранности и попытаюсь!